# What does >1../log/orientdb.log and 1>>../log/orientdb.log mean in shell scripting?

Tags: shell

I am currently customizing a shell script that is used to launch a database called OrientDb.

These are the relevant lines from the script in question:

```
sudo -u $ORIENTDB_USER sh -c "cd \"$ORIENTDB_DIR/bin\"; /usr/bin/nohup ./server.sh 1>../log/orientdb.log 2>../log/orientdb.err &"

sudo -u $ORIENTDB_USER sh -c "cd \"$ORIENTDB_DIR/bin\"; /usr/bin/nohup ./shutdown.sh 1>>../log/orientdb.log 2>>../log/orientdb.err &"
```

I understand that the script sudos to a user defined in `ORIENTDB_USER` and runs a few commands. I also understand that the `&` forces the script to run in the background.

However, when calling the `server.sh` and `shutdown.sh` scripts, it is appended with `1>../log/orient.err` and `1>>../log/orientdb.err`.

What does `1>` and `1>>` mean? What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 >  redirects stdout and writes it to a file named like the argument provided.

2 > would do the same for stderr.

1 >> does it but appends to a file instead of rewriting it, if it exists already.

| would pass the output to the next process.

Search for shell redirection if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

1> redirects std out to the log file, 1>> appends to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

`1` redirects standard output. `>` means "create a file here if none exists, or wipe a file if it does exist". `>>` means "append to a current file".

Hence, `1> ../log/orient.err` writes standard output to `../log/orient.err`, wiping any previous file with that name. `1>> ../log/orientdb.err` writes standard output to the same file, but preserving the file and appending to the end of it.